# Include string in front of list of files as command

Tags: bash

I have some data labeled as such:

```
4772-JW-10_S129_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
4772-JW-1_S17_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
4772-JW-1_S17_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
4772-JW-1_S17_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
4772-JW-2_S121_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
4772-JW-3_S122_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
4772-JW-4_S123_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
4772-JW-5_S124_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
4772-JW-7_S126_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
4772-JW-9_S128_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E10_HKHCWDSXX_S12_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E10_HKHCWDSXX_S12_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E10_HKHCWDSXX_S12_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E10_HKHCWDSXX_S12_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E6_HKHCWDSXX_S9_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E6_HKHCWDSXX_S9_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E6_HKHCWDSXX_S9_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E6_HKHCWDSXX_S9_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E8_HKHCWDSXX_S10_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E8_HKHCWDSXX_S10_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E8_HKHCWDSXX_S10_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E8_HKHCWDSXX_S10_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E8_HKHFNDSXX_S21_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E8_HKHFNDSXX_S21_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E8_HKHFNDSXX_S21_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E8_HKHFNDSXX_S21_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E9_HKHCWDSXX_S11_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E9_HKHCWDSXX_S11_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E9_HKHCWDSXX_S11_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-E9_HKHCWDSXX_S11_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F3_HKHCWDSXX_S13_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F3_HKHCWDSXX_S13_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F3_HKHCWDSXX_S13_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F3_HKHCWDSXX_S13_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F4_HKHCWDSXX_S14_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F4_HKHCWDSXX_S14_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F4_HKHCWDSXX_S14_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F4_HKHCWDSXX_S14_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F5_HKHCWDSXX_S15_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F5_HKHCWDSXX_S15_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F5_HKHCWDSXX_S15_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F5_HKHCWDSXX_S15_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F7_HKHCWDSXX_S16_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F7_HKHCWDSXX_S16_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F7_HKHCWDSXX_S16_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-F7_HKHCWDSXX_S16_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-G3_HKHCWDSXX_S30_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-G3_HKHCWDSXX_S30_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-G3_HKHCWDSXX_S30_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-G3_HKHCWDSXX_S30_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-G7_HKHCWDSXX_S31_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-G7_HKHCWDSXX_S31_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-G7_HKHCWDSXX_S31_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
MDA-G7_HKHCWDSXX_S31_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
SPR-C57-AAI-clone-3C_HKHCWDSXX_S8_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
SPR-C57-AAI-clone-3C_HKHCWDSXX_S8_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
SPR-C57-AAI-clone-3C_HKHCWDSXX_S8_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
SPR-C57-AAI-clone-3C_HKHCWDSXX_S8_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
SPR-C57-p11-bulk_HKHJHDSXX_S11_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
SPR-C57-p11-bulk_HKHJHDSXX_S11_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
SPR-C57-p11-bulk_HKHJHDSXX_S11_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
SPR-C57-p11-bulk_HKHJHDSXX_S11_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
SPR-C57-UNT-clone-2C_HKHCWDSXX_S7_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
SPR-C57-UNT-clone-2C_HKHCWDSXX_S7_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
SPR-C57-UNT-clone-2C_HKHCWDSXX_S7_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
SPR-C57-UNT-clone-2C_HKHCWDSXX_S7_L004.aligned.unsorted.bam
```

I would like to run software using these samples, but I need to somehow group the files of the same run but different type (marked by `L00...`), so for example:

```
Name: 4772-JW-1_S17
Subtypes: 
4772-JW-1_S17_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam
4772-JW-1_S17_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam
4772-JW-1_S17_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam
```

and pass it into a program that takes in commands as such:

```
java -jar file.jar GenericProgram \
I=4772-JW-1_S17_L001.aligned.unsorted.bam \
I=4772-JW-1_S17_L002.aligned.unsorted.bam \
I=4772-JW-1_S17_L003.aligned.unsorted.bam \
O=output
```

The program command takes in files but has `I=` before each file. I want to create separate commands for each run I have in the dataset. Is there a way I can go through the data I have, get the types for each run, and pass it into the command through bash?

Comment: Is your input list in three columns like in your question?

Comment: No, have corrected, see post

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
java -jar file.jar GenericProgram $(for f in 4772-JW-1_S17* ; do echo "I=$f " ; done) O=output
```

Comment: Do you have a solution for extending this to every run serially? ie. not just `4772-JW-1_S17`, but also `4772-JW-10_S129...`, `4772-JW-2_S121...`, `MDA-E8_HKHFNDSXX_S21...`, etc.